# Requested resource not found for sub-context in case of JSF

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, tomcat6, faces-config

My JSF application is deployed under tomcat and server.xml is configured as follows for my application

```
   <Host name="myapp.com" appBase="/home/myapp/public_html">
      <Alias>www.myapp.com</Alias>
      <Context path="" reloadable="true" docBase="/home/myapp/public_html" debug="1"/>
      <Context path="/manager" debug="0" privileged="true" docBase="/usr/local/jakarta/tomcat/server/webapps/manager">
      </Context>
   </Host>
```

With these settings I can access all the pages under 'web' folder. I have 'app' folder under 'web' and I have couple of jsp pages under 'app', when I try to access some pages available under 'app' with the following URL: `www.myapp.com/app/test_page.jsf`, I get 'requested resource cannot be found'

What are the changes I need to do in Tomcat`s Server.xml to get this working.

Do I need to add context path for the 'app' subcontext like this mentioned below in Server.xml:

```
<Context path="/myapp/app" reloadable="true" docBase="/home/myapp/public_html/app" debug="1"/>
```

Comment: You're struggling with this problem for really long, isn't it? This is already the nth question you asked about exactly the same core problem without improving the previous unaccepted questions. In the future, please improve the questions rather than re-asking the question about basically the same problem again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `/web` folder is placed in `/public_html` folder, you need to include the `/web` folder in either `appBase` and `docBase`, or in URL.

Comment: pages under web works well, the problem I have with is with the pages under 'app' folder

Comment: You told that the `/app` folder is placed in `/web` folder, but you aren't specifying the `/web` folder anywhere in `server.xml` or in URL. You need to correct this.